# Update Query with a Twist - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Column name "Height", the table has millions of records

The Records are show for example

```
18-24"
30-36"
36-42"
12-15"
```

and so on...

What i want to do is update the Column so that it looks like below

```
18-24 inch
30-36 inch
36-42 inch
12-15 inch
```

Is this possible in MYSQL using SQL Query or i have to do it manually by exporting it in XLS and then find replace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
UPDATE Height SET your_column = REPLACE(your_column, '"', ' inch')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update yourTable 
set height = replace(height, '"', ' inch')
```